# Undoing an over tight Clove Hitch?

Tags: knots, slacklining, clove-hitch

The weather has been really nice this weekend in North wales so over the weekend I set up a slack line in my back garden to have a play about on!

On Sun I went to take it all down. Problem is I attached one end of the line to a carabiner using a clove hitch, it appears this was a big mistake. The hitch is now totally locked up and I can't undo or move the knot, it's been under tension for about 2 days. In hindsight this was probably not the knot to use here...

Can anyone suggest any good tricks to loosing the knot off? or do I have to cut the thing off?

Seen someone suggest a ["Fid"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fid). But I obviously don't own one of these? Alternatives?

Comment: Next time, use two carabiners instead of one. That makes it a lot easier to undo a clove hitch.

Comment: Hi Liam. Respectfully, I'm wondering if this question falls into our scope. If it does, then wouldn't any activity we do outside in the yard be included? There's a similar one that has appeared since this, and I have the same concern there. Can you help me understand what makes this on-topic? Thanks!

Comment: Hey @sue. I've sent you a [chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38292735#38292735)

Comment: Hi Liam,  Thanks much for the chat message. I appreciate your time, and also letting me know it was there, as I don't always get my notifications! I have to call the Geek Squad (the American group of computer-fixers!), to fix my computer, and do a few things but I promise I'll answer sometime today. We can erase these comments if you want, including my first one. Thanks again!

Comment: @Liam I replied to your chat message. I'm sorry it took so long. By the time the awesome Geeks fixed my computer, it was night time where you live. I think my objection was misguided, and the question is in scope, and am sorry I put you through this. Thanks for your politeness and understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the [suggestion by B540Glenn](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/16333/2766). Unfortunately this resulted in a very broken pencil and not much progress. It did though inspire me!

I figured if I had something pencil shaped but stronger this would probably work. Digging though my tool box I came across a [nail set](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-Nail-Set+Centre-Punch/p/500068):

[image]

I figured this would be perfect. So I set to work forcing the set into the gaps between the ropes:

Place the set into a suitable gap, hammer gently ensuring the set is going between the coils and not though them:
[image]
[image: Starting to get though]
[image: Set though coil of the rope]

After doing this a couple of times in a couple of places and some gentle levering the knot started to loosen. After a couple of minutes it was loose enough to slip off.

[image: Released biner and rope. Note the broken pencil and black marks (from the pencil lead) on the rope!]

Word of warning, this has done some minor damage to the carabiner and rope. I don't use this rope or biner for climbing so I'm not really bothered but you might want to be wary/more careful than me if you want to keep using these items afterwards for climbing. I mostly use this rope for slacklining.

Comment: I am not sure whether this biner was aluminum, but it could be, so a warning (please excuse me if the biner is steel): Aluminum biners are not suited for constant high loads (even less if the forces change around a high value). You should always use steel biners for slacklines and if an aluminum was used, retire it.

Comment: Hi @imsodin the biner was steel. Good shout though.

Comment: Why the minus one?

Comment: I always string a small length of cord into the knot when I'm tying it, so if it does get super tight I can use the cord to work it loose instead of prying it apart with a tool. You have to be preemptive for this to work though, you could also use second carabiner, stick, zip tie, anything that you have on you really.

Comment: The traditional tool for loosening tight knots is a marlinspike, not a fid. (Both are tools used in rope work, but a fid will generally be weaker and larger depending on the size of rope its intended for.) A good makeshift marlinspike is an icepick with the tip filed down, rounded and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

How about a pencil? I use a pencil to add a little play into stubborn knots.  Don't use a very sharp point, use one that has a rounded point to avoid puncturing the line.

I don't climb so the line I use is nautical in nature.  You may want to treat your climbing line more carefully.

Comment: Good idea, this knot is really really tight though. I'll try it tonight but I'm not sure this will be strong enough

Comment: You could use a screw driver (better handle than a pencil -  more force). inspect the rope very carefully and consider retiring it for anything really important.  I have always managed to work them loose, but I have never had a rope as tight as a slack line held by a CH.